# google smart home action device type icon issue

Tags: google-smart-home

I am trying to implement dimmer switch,
devices type I use as below:
action.devices.types.SWITCH"

it include two devices traits as below:

1. action.devices.traits.Brightness
2. action.devices.traits.OnOff

But in google home App, the icon shows a Bulb icon, not switch icon, why?
Any setting I miss?

Thank you.
BR,
Jack

Comment: What is the name of the device?

Comment: My device name set to Dimmer

Comment: There are certain names that will result in a switch being interpreted as a different device type. Naming a switch as 'Light' will result in the app assuming that specific device is a light even if the device classification is a switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Home app allows the following device types to be modified by the user to **represent the device that is being controlled**:

- [action.devices.types.SWITCH](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/guides/switch)
- [action.devices.types.OUTLET](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/guides/outlet)

Users can adjust this value by going into the device settings and selecting **Device type** (this option is only available for the listed devices). This derived type defines the icon that appears in the home view.

By default, the Google Home app tries to derive this selected type from the provided device name during `SYNC` when it contains known values such as "light" or "lamp".